# Issue on Guava jar

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, guava

While writing on elasticsearch **2.3.3** through hadoop job, job fails due to guava issue ,which is hadoop has 11.02 version guava.jar but guava 18.0 is required.Can I exclude hadoop internal jar from pom.xml file?If so how can i exclude?

Comment: An internet search of "maven exclude dependency" gives https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html  Would have taken 5 secs

Comment: I have tried as : <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> but it is not working .Please suggest what was my mistake?

Comment: That is what "mvn --debug" is for.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [a blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/to-shade-or-not-to-shade) which explains a method to deal with some JAR conflicts. I hope this could help.

Basically, you could shade elasticsearch project or your conflicting jar.

Comment: The main problem is ,hadoop internally have guava version 11.02 but while writing on ES 2.3.3 guava 18.0 is required,How can we use jar from our project instead of jar inside /hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib. Thanks